# Issue with LabelEncoder and zip python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, scikit-learn

I have a bunch of lists `y1,y2..yn`, each containing string instances belonging to multiple classes. I am looking to encode them into numerical classes for training an LSTM. What I am trying is:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
enc1 = LabelEncoder()
enc2 = LabelEncoder()
enc3 = LabelEncoder()

encoders = [enc1, enc2, enc3]
labels = [y1, y2, y3]

for i,j in zip(encoders, labels):
    j = i.fit_transform(j)
```

However, the outputs are still the same string classes for all the lists when I try:

```
print(format(Counter(y2)))
# Out: Counter({'m': 125585, 'f': 52589})
```

Only when encoded individually, does the `LabelEncoder` seem to work, showing integer classes:

```
y2 = enc2.fit_transform(y2)
print(format(Counter(y2)))
# Out: Counter({1: 52589, 0: 125585})
```

What could be the issue with the `zip` method?

Comment: You are assigning the output of label_encoder to a temporary loop variable `j`, it will not reflect in the actual list. You need to explicilty replace the element in list or better make a new list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cleaner and more-pythonic solution is *list comprehension*:

```
transformed = [i.fit_transform(j) for i, j in zip(encoders, labels)]
```

... which will save you from bugs with reusing `j` in a loop.